# How to find a fitting power law?

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics

Given the following set of xs and ys:

xs = [8294400, 2073600, 921600, 409920]

ys = [124, 433, 853, 1449]

Fitting this with a power law in Excel yields a good approximation:

[image]

Excel found a function of the form `a(x^b)`. How can one determine `a` and `b` in C#? I tried using Math.Net numerics but I don't see any method that would work for a function of this form. All the functions in the [Linear Regression module](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Regression.html) just find linear coefficients to functions of various forms but none seem to be able to determine an exponent.

Comment: That is because the kind of regression you want is nonlinear.

Comment: You may need http://metanumerics.codeplex.com/ and the documentation http://metanumerics.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tests&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: This case is actually described on the linked page: http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Regression.html#Linearizing-non-linear-models-by-transformation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation you want looks like this:

```
y = a*x^b
```

Take the natural log of both sides:

```
ln(y) = ln(a*x^b) = ln(a) + b*ln(x)
```

Now you can use linear regression on the new transformed variables `(ln(x), ln(y))` and calculate the two parameters you want: `ln(a)` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

In an exponential system, the best way to do a regression is probably by doing a linear regression on a log scale. To clarify, even though your function isn't linear, taking the natural log of both sides of the equation will result in a more linear system

Non-linear function: `y = a x^b`

This then becomes `ln(y) = ln(a x^b) = ln(a) b ln(x)`

In Math.NET Numerics, a good way to code it could be:

```
var y = y.Select(r => Math.Log(r)).ToArray(); // transform y = ln(z)
double[] w = Fit.LinearCombination(xy, z_hat,
    d => 1.0,
    d => Math.Log(d[0]),
    d => Math.Log(d[1]))
```

Or if you wanted to have it return a function you could use `LinearCombinationFunc()`

Sources: http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Regression.html and http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/Fit.htm

Comment: This is incorrect; you left out the ln(a) term.  What I wrote is correct.

Comment: RIght. That's a typo.